# Creating multiple @XmlRootElements from same Jaxb schema file

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have the following JAXB .xsd schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
       jaxb:version="2.1" xmlns="some.namespace.com"
       targetNamespace="some.namespace.com">

    <xs:element name="outerModel">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:class name="OuterModelDto" />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="innerModel" type="innerModelDto" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="innerModelDto">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fullname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="surname" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This will create an `OuterModelDto` and an `InnerModelDto` class. The `OuterModelDto` is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`, but the `InnerModelDto` is not. How can i ensure that `InnerModelDto` is also annotated with `@XmlRootElement`?

One solution was to  wrap the `innerModelDto complexType` in an element, which meant that i did end up with `@XmlRootElement` on both `Dto`s, but during serialization of `OuterModelDto`, the namespace information was serialized, which i do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the `complexType` and `element` definitions in the schema. Each `element` will result in a `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Make sure you declare some namespace prefix in your schema to be able to refer to the types, see the `xmlns:tns` here:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
   jaxb:version="2.1"
   targetNamespace="some.namespace.com"
   xmlns:tns="some.namespace.com">

    <xs:complexType name="OuterModelDto">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="innerModel" type="innerModelDto" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="InnerModelDto">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fullname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="surname" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="outerModel" type="tns:OuterModelDto" />
    <xs:element name="innterModel" type="tns:InnerModelDto" />

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) to annotate `innerModelDto` with `@XmlRootElement`. See (and upvote) this answer by Xstian:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26545603/303810

The binding would be like:

```
<bindings node="xs:complexType[@type='innerModelDto']">
    <annox:annotateClass>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="innerModel")</annox:annotateClass>
</bindings>
```

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).